# derivation qm canonical ensemble

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics

In classical mechanics the canonical ensemble can be derived from the microcanonical ensemble of two systems in weak interaction. Is a similar thing possible in quantum mechanics? Is there any good derivation for the qm canonical ensemble (except appealing to that it shd commute with the Hamiltonian).

Edit: So after one knows that $$\rho=\sum P_n |E_n><E_n|$$ (up to normalization), the derivation given below calculates the $P_n$. How can we know that $\rho$ is of this form. E.g wouldnt $$\rho= |\psi><\psi|$$ with $$|\psi> = \sum \sqrt{P_n} |E_n>$$ also solve the Problem? Plainly saying $\rho$ has to commute with $H$ seems a bit ad-hoc to me.

Comment: Do you mean how to derive the fact that the equilibrium state of a system at a given temperature is the Gibbs state? Have you ever heard the name "KMS-state"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways how the canonical ensemble can be derived (or maybe better say justified) in classical and quantum mechanics. Possible ways include:

1. From the micro-canonical ensemble: This is essentially the approach outlined the answer by Sebastian Riese and addresses most directly your question. The short answer is yes, this is possible. However, the weak coupling limit in quantum mechanics is not as strait forward as in classical physics and the existing derivations are still not satisfying in all respects
2. As states dynamically emerging during quantum evolution: The canonical state of either a subsystem or of the whole system are found to describe well the values that the expectation values of certain observables dynamically seemingly "equilibrate" to while a large closed interacting quantum system evolves in time. There are both theorems (that work in certain scenarios) as well as many numerical studies on this.
3. Justification by a maximum entropy principle: In finite dimensional quantum mechanics, the canonical state is the unique state that maximizes the von Neumann entropy for a given fixed expectation value of the energy. The maximum entropy principle can in turn be made plausible by arguing that it leads to a "least biased" choice if all one knows about a system is the expectation value of its energy. Again, there are some subtleties here.
4. Resource theoretic justification: A family of approaches towards thermodynamics that can be subsumed under the term "resource theories" concentrate on what can be done with a given set or quantum states if one is able to perform certain operations on them. An important class of states within such frameworks are the so called "passive states". These are states from which no energy/work can be extracted by certain sets of thermodynamics operations. It turns out that the canonical state is the only state that is still passive even if one has access to many copies of this state at the same time.

For some more details, especially on point 1-2 and partially on point 3 see for example my recent [review paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.07538).

Answer (score 1):

There is a method I like. It appears in the book H. Schulz: "Statistische Mechanik" (Harry Deutsch, 2005) (to my knowledge only available in German).
It runs as follows:

Consider a bath weakly coupled to a system, together they are prepared micro-canonically at energy $E$. The Hamiltonian of the system have only non-degenerate eigenenergies (otherwise we can disturb it slightly, to make the eigenstates non-degenerate, which should not have observable consequences).

If the system has an energy $E_n$, then the bath will have energy $E - E_n$ and be $\nu_n$-fold degenerate. So the total degeneracy of the system plus the bath is given by $\nu = \sum_n \nu_n$. The $\nu_n$ decrease with increasing $E_n$, as the entropy of the bath will decrease with decreasing bath energy.

The very assumption of the micro-canonical ensemble is that all degenerate states are equally likely. Therefore, the probability for the system to be in state $n$ is given by
$$ P_n = \frac{\nu_n}{\nu}. $$

Now consider (using that the microcanonical entropy is given by $S = \ln(\nu)$):
\begin{align*}
\ln(P_n) &= \ln(\nu_n) - \ln(\nu) = S_\text{bath}(E - E_n) - S_\text{total}(E) \\
&= - S_\text{total}(E) + S_\text{bath} (E) - E_n \partial_E S_\text{bath}(E) \\
&= - S_\text{total}(E) + S_\text{bath} (E) - \beta E_n
\end{align*}
Where we Taylor-expanded $S_\text{bath}$ around $E$, this is valid, as $E_n \ll E$ will always hold. As $- S_\text{total} + S_\text{bath} (E)$ will be independent of $n$ we get
$$P_n \propto e^{-\beta E_n}. $$
From this we get the canonical probability distribution by using $\sum_n P_n = 1$:
$$P_n = \frac 1 Z e^{-\beta E_n}$$
$$Z = \sum_n e^{-\beta E_n}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the derivation. This answer half of it. I clarified the question.

Comment: The answer is still this derivation. The point is, that we prepare an ensemble, and an ensemble cannot be represented by a wavefunction, but only by a density matrix (as the systems in the ensemble do not interfere). Furthermore, it is not ad-hoc to assume that $\rho$ commutes with $H$; if $\rho$ did not commute with $H$ it would not describe a steady state (by the von Neumann equation), and equilibrium must (by definition) be a  steady state.