# Derive Density Matrix of Canonical Ensemble by Tracing out the Reservoir

Tags: statistical-mechanics, density-operator

I would like to ask about a possible way to derive the (quantum mechanical) density matrix of the canonical ensemble:

$$
\rho = \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\beta H}
$$

I want to proceed as follows: It is known that for a composite system consisting of two parts $A$ and $B$, if we want to measure a quantity (say $O_A$) that involves only part $A$, we can use the reduced density matrix

$$
\rho_A = \text{Tr}_B \rho
$$

Here $\rho$ is the density matrix of the composite system $AB$. Then the expectation value of $O_A$ is $\langle O_A \rangle = \text{Tr} (\rho_A O_A)$. To some extent, we can say that the subsystem $A$ is described by $\rho_A$.

But the canonical ensemble in statistical mechanics describes a (relatively small) system (let's call it $A$) that can exchange heat with a (very large) reservoir (called $B$). The composite system $AB$ is completely closed, and may be described by the microcanonical ensemble.

The microcanonical ensemble has a very simple density matrix: if there are $g$ microscopic states $|\psi_1\rangle, ..., |\psi_g\rangle$ satisfying the "macroscopic constraints" (such as given energy, number of particles, volume, etc.), then for the whole system $AB$,

$$
\rho = \sum_{n=1}^{g} \frac{1}{g} | \psi_n \rangle \langle \psi_n |
$$

Then is it possible to derive the canonical density matrix by tracing out the reservoir $B$ (i.e. $\rho_A = \text{Tr}_B \rho$)? What extra assumptions are needed?

*P.S. I hope that this can be done in a way that is accessible for an undergraduate physics student.*

Comment: Tracing out B leads to a Lindblad master equation. It will involve jump operators describing the energy exchange with $B$ (the reservoir). I am unaware on a precise way to get the proper ones, that correspond to thermal exchange. There are some recent works though, that suggest strong dissipation of any kind, often (but not always) leads to thermal-like behavior regarding the critical properties of $A$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [derivation qm canonical ensemble](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185617/derivation-qm-canonical-ensemble)

Comment: (On the other hand, this question is better formulated than the one I link to, in my opinion...)

Comment: The review article in that linked question seems to be good, but I may need some time to understand what the authors are saying...

Comment: Yes, the review paper is pretty long. The part related to your question seems to be Section 7.3 (you probably already found that out, but this may be useful for other people).